# Allowing HTTPS through the pfSense Firewall

Tags: networking, firewall, pfsense

I've included my current setup.

However, when I try and access the firewall from outside my organization, I only get this:

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

Am I not the correct protocols through?

[image]

EDIT:

(not mentioned is above this ruleset I back a default catch and block ALL for ALL protocols thinking that I set a block all then allow on a case by case basis.)

So I narrowed down the issue... I think. Apparently, it works fine if you leave the protocol blocked to TCP/UDP. But the moment you try and block ALL protocols it seems to also break OpenVPN and HTTPS.

Maybe I need to allow one of the other protocols as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it.

Apparently you have to put the ALLOW rules first then you put in the BLOCK rules when doing firewall rules on the WAN interface.

Answer (score 2):

Besides the firewall rule you mentioned, you also need to add port forward rule which points to the internal web server. The idea is when pfsense firewall detects a network connection to TCP port 443, it will redirect the traffic to internal web server TCP port 443.

Follow the steps below to create a port forward under pfsense: (I assume your internal web server has ip address of ***192.168.1.1***)

After logging into pfsense, goto **Firewall --> NAT**
[image: NAT Page]

Choose **Port Forward:**, then choose the create button from the right hand side:
[image: Port Forward mainpage]

Create port forward similar to the screen shown below:
[image: Create Port Forward]

Save the change and you should be ready to go.

Comment: However, I am not port forwarding in this case since pfSense listens on the public IP address.

Comment: You also need to perform port forwarding to redirect outside traffic to internal web server. Glad to know you have fixed the problem.